# How to extract all configurable products (name,sku,brand,tier prices) from Magento (sql query)?

Tags: mysql, magento, mage

I need to extract configurable products only from magento. I need a query to perform it or model to work with configurable products.

Comment: what data do you actually need?

Comment: I need to select all configurable products for pdf product list. 

I need it next way:
product_name, product_sku, product_brand and also tier price params in next way (qty=>price)

let me know if you didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $_productCollection = $this ->getLoadedProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable');

 //print_r($_productCollection);

 foreach($_productCollection as $product){
     echo $product->getSku();
     .....

 }
```

Then pass this info into your function to create the pdf like this [How to create a pdf in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914108/how-to-create-a-pdf-in-magento)

See more @ [Magento - load only configurable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280392/magento-load-only-configurable-products)

Answer (score 0):

The menu `System / Import-Export` of the Backoffice is designed for this purpose.

particularly the `Dataflow - Profiles` entry where you have a "Export all product" profile customisable/filterable with a assitant.

You can use the CSV/XML/whatever generated to generate a PDF (your call)